# char pointers: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I cut out all the unnecessary code so no one gets too bored with my question... So I cant get the char array to work! on the last few lines of

```
*whatname = guyname; 
*whatlastname = lastname;
```

I get an error saying  invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'. Help would be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void getname(char *whatname, char *whatlastname);

int main()
{
    int option = 0;
    char guyname = 'x';
    char lastname = 'x';
    bool name_entered = false;

    do{
        printf("1. Enter name.\n");
        printf("2. Enter exam scores.\n");
        printf("3. Display average exam scores. \n");
        printf("4. Display summary. \n");
        printf("5. Quit. \n");
        scanf("%i", &option);

        if( option == 1 )
        {
            name_entered = true;
            getname(&guyname, &lastname);
        }
    else if( option == 4 )
    {
        {
            printf("%s %s based on your exam scores of \n",guyname, lastname);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter your name in option 1 and you exam scores in option 2 before continuing.\n");
        }
    }
        else if( option == 5 )
        {
            printf(" Come back with a better grade next time.");
            break;
        }
    }while (!(option >5 || option <1));
    return 0;
}

void getname (char *whatname, char *whatlastname)
{
    char guyname[32];
    char lastname[32];
    printf("Enter your first and last name : ");
    scanf("%s %s", &guyname, &lastname);

    guyname[0] = toupper( guyname[0] );
    int len = strlen(guyname);
    for(int i=1; i<len ; i++)
    {
        guyname[i] = tolower( guyname[i]);
    }

    lastname[0] = toupper( lastname[0] );
    int len1 = strlen(lastname);
    for(int k=1; k<len1; k++)
    {
        lastname[k]= tolower( lastname[k]);
    }

    printf("Your name is %s %s\n", guyname, lastname);
    *whatname = guyname;
    *whatlastname = lastname;
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with void-pointers

Comment: You might like to read about `strcpy()` and how "strings" are represented in C.

Comment: Your code misses soemthing here: `    else if( option == 4 )
    {
        {  ` between the two opening braces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dealing with `char`, `char*`, and `char []` in C is a little confusing in the beginning.

Take a look at the following statements:

```
char str1[] = "abcd";
char const* str2 = "xyz";
char* cp = str1;
char c = *cp;
```

The first statement and the second statement are identical in their behavior. After the first statement is executed, `str1` points to a location that contains 4 characters, in consecutive order. If you think of the memory locations for the string, you might see something like:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
```

`str1` points to the address where `a` is stored. There is a similar arrangement for storing the string `"xyz"` and `str2` points to the address where `x` is stored.

In the third statement, you are creating `cp` and making it point where `str1` is pointing. After that statement, both `cp` and `str1` point to the same string - `"abcd"`.

`*cp` evaluates to the character that exists at the address that `cp` points to. In this case, it will be `'a'`.

In the fourth statement, you are initializing `c` with `'a'`, the character that exists at the address pointed to by `cp`.

Now, if you try a statement

```
*cp = str2;
```

it is a compiler error. `*cp` simply dereferences the address of `cp`. You can put a `char` at that location, not `str2`, which is a `char*`.

You can execute

```
*cp = *str2;
```

After that, the objects in the memory that `str1` and `cp` point to will look like:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| x | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
```

If you want to copy the string from the address pointed to by `str1` to the address pointed to by `cp`, you can use the standard library function `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(cp, str2);
```

You have to be careful about using `strcpy` because you have to have enough valid memory to copy to. In this particular example, if you tried

```
char str3[2];
strcpy(str3, cp);
```

you will get undefined behavior since there isn't enough memory in `str3` to be able to copy  `"abcd"`.

Hope that made sense.

Here's a modified version of your code that should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void getname(char *whatname, char *whatlastname);

int main()
{
    int option = 0;
    char guyname[32];
    char lastname[32];
    bool name_entered = false;

    do{
        printf("1. Enter name.\n");
        printf("2. Enter exam scores.\n");
        printf("3. Display average exam scores. \n");
        printf("4. Display summary. \n");
        printf("5. Quit. \n");
        scanf("%i", &option);

        if( option == 1 )
        {
            name_entered = true;
            getname(guyname, lastname);
        }
        else if( option == 5 )
        {
            printf(" Come back with a better grade next time.");
            break;
        }
    }while (!(option >5 || option <1));
    return 0;
}

void getname (char *whatname, char *whatlastname)
{
    char guyname[32];
    char lastname[32];
    printf("Enter your first and last name : ");
    scanf("%31s %31s", guyname, lastname);

    guyname[0] = toupper( guyname[0] );
    int len = strlen(guyname);
    for(int i=1; i<len ; i++)
    {
        guyname[i] = tolower( guyname[i]);
    }

    lastname[0] = toupper( lastname[0] );
    int len1 = strlen(lastname);
    for(int k=1; k<len1; k++)
    {
        lastname[k]= tolower( lastname[k]);
    }

    printf("Your name is %s %s\n", guyname, lastname);
    strcpy(whatname, guyname);
    strcpy(whatlastname,lastname);
}
```

Comment: Althought the correct approach, better have `scanf("%s %s", &guyname, &lastname);` being `scanf("%31s %31s", &guyname, &lastname);` to avoid overflowing `guyname` and `lastname`. +1 hoewever.

Comment: Good suggestion @alk. The line is updated to `scanf("%31s %31s", guyname, lastname);'

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: @RSahu: can you kindly explain how `*cp = *str2;` could result str1 and cp to look like: `| x | b | c | d |`?

Comment: @Sampath, `cp` points to the first character of the array defined by `str`. The statement `*cp = *str2` assigns the `x` to that location. Hence, the characters in the arra are `| x | b | c | d |`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

lot of things wrong here. You need to think about where the two string are going to be stored.

You are trying to return variable on the stack of getname - even if you fix the C code that wont work.

```
a) getname needs to be getname(char**, char**)

b) whatname and whatLastname need to be char *

c) call getname with (&whatname &whatLastName)

d) strdup the strings in getname into the two params (*whatname,...)
```

Comment: I assume I was downvoted because of strdup and hence the requirement to free?

Comment: I didn't down vote personally but only because it's already at -1, Your wording is horribly unclear as well. 'needs to be'?  And why is your whole thing inside a code block?  Your answer also doesn't explain why for any of it, so it is of little use.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pair of values in the main which are single characters.

You're passing in pointers to those characters, then dereferencing them (which gives you single characters again), then trying to assign character pointers to them. That definitely isn't going to work.

Even if you did,

```
whatname = guyname; 
whatlastname = lastname;
```

which would be type-correct, it wouldn't do what you seem to want, which is to change the values in the calling function. It would only change the values of the argument variables in the subroutine.

If you're trying to return two strings found in the subroutine, change the calling code's variables to:

```
char *guyname = "x";
char *lastname = "x";
```

and change the function arguments to

```
void getname (char **whatname, char **whatlastname)
```

Then your assignment will be type-correct, and will change the pointers in the calling function.

Comment: Sry, but the memomry `char * guyname = ""` is pointing to is read-only.

Comment: @alk: True. But the _pointer_ guyname is not, and that's what my proposal alters. Reread, please.

Comment: Fair enough. (Why however you are assigning something to `guyname` at all?) You probaoby should add that `getname()` would be responsible to assign memory to the pointers passed in which would still be valid on the function's return.

Comment: You might like to touch your answer, so I could undo my downvote?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be `&` in `scanf` of string.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, using * on a pointer will dereference it (you did it on the last two lines)
secondly, you are sending to the function a pointer to a single char, not an array of chars so if you will write to its memory you will write on some other variable's memory. 
What you should have done is declaring guysname and lastname as char arrays

```
char guysname[32];
```

and in your function just read your input directly into the parameters you recieve:

```
scanf("%s %s", whatname, whatlastname);
```

replace all instances of guysname and lastname for whatname and whatlastname. get rid of the last lines.
If you want to keep the char arrays inside the function anyway, just use

```
strcpy(whatname,guysname)
```

and the same for the last name.

Comment: I think you mean dereference it.

Answer (score -2):

You can't assign a char value to a char pointer, and you can't dereference an Lvalue.

```
whatname = &guyname;
whatlastname = &guylastname;
```

This is what you're looking for. However, it appears that you're just starting to play with pointers, and you may need to read up on them a little more before you start experimenting.

Comment: Your approach would return a refernrce to memory which is living on the function's stack, which is bad idea, as this memory is invalid as soon as the functin had returned.

Comment: So are you suggesting that you *can* dereference an Lvalue and that you *can* assign a char value to a char pointer?